# Извлечь введённую в EditText информацию из ListView

Tags: android

У меня есть `ListView`, наполненный из `SimpleCursorAdapter` данными из базы данных, в `ListView` форма строк задана из XML-файла.

Как вытащить введённую пользователем информацию из каждой строки `ListView`? Основная проблема в том, что не получается достать информацию из строк, которых в данный момент на экране нет (весь `ListView` на экране не помещается).

Comment: Введенную информацию нужно сразу после ввода сохранять - либо в промежуточное хранилище (вроде массива данных или коллекции), либо сразу в БД. Айтемы переиспользуются и с большой долей вероятности будут утрачены при скроллинге безвозвратно.

Comment: это я уже понял , но какой метод именно использовать? EditText просто находится в другом View(LinearLayout), и при нажатии именно на EditText,метод OnItemClick не вызывается, пробовал задать ему метод onClick, но он вызывается только если два раза кликнуть по одному EditText,  каким методом и из какого интерфейса пользоваться? Думал о afterTextChanged(Editable s) из TextWatch, но не нашёл как его назначить из XML файла(потому что не могу понять как именно получить ссылку на EditText после того как пользователь начал редактирование) @pavlofff

Comment: Что должно происходить с введенными данными в дальнейшем?  Окончание ввода как то подтверждается, вроде кноки *ОК*  в айтеме списка ?

Comment: нет, ввод подтверждается только после того как пользователь заполнит все EditText в ListView(подтверждение полного ввода производится через кнопку вне ListView), то есть в начале все данные собираются в массив, а потом уже проверяются их соответствие с базой данных ответов, я хотел чтобы при нажатии на новый EditText из предыдущего нажатого вытаскивались данные, но не сработало.@pavlofff

Comment: сейчас думаю просто при скролинге перебирать все айтемы, которые выведены на экран. @pavlofff

Comment: другого пока ничего в голову не лезет @pavlofff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вам надо написать собственный кастомный адаптер на основе `SimpleCursorAdapter`, который будет реализовывать требующуюся функциональность. Там необходимо переопределить метод `bindView()`, ответственный за вывод виджетов в айтем.
2. Если подтверждения ввода в каждый `EditText` нет, то необходимо использовать слушатель `OnFocusChangeListener()`, привязанный к `EditText`-ам айтемов. Слушатель будет срабатывать при потере фокуса в `EditText`, что значит, что в данном поле ввод закончен и пользователь перешел к другому полю.
3. Введенная информация должна собираться в какое то хранилище, например массив. В адаптере необходимо организовать метод, который отдаст этот массив "наружу", когда он потребуется.

Примерно код может выглядеть так, писал все "на коленке" и он, скорее всего не полностью рабочий, а только для демонстрации алгоритма. Так же неплохо бы использовать `ViewHolder`:

```
public class EditAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    String mEnterTexts[];
    private Context mContext;
    private int mLayout;
    private Cursor mCursor;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;

   public EditAdapter(Context context,int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context,layout,c,from,to);
    mLayout=layout;
    mContext = context;
    mCursorr=c;
    // получаем сколько строк надо запомнить.
    enterTexts = new enterTexts[mCursor.getCount()]; 
}


    @Override
    public View newView (Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
                return inflater.inflate(mLayout, null);
        }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

        EditText edit = view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        edit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus){
                    int position = cursor.getPosition();
                    mEnterTexts[position] = edit.getText().toString();
                }
            }
        });
   }
 }
 public String[] getEnterTexts(){
 return mEnterTexts;
}
```

При обработке клика на кнопке в конце ввода вы можете получить введенные значения в виде массива из экземпляра созданного адаптера:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    String[] enteredTexts = mAdapter.getEnterTexts();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! идею я понял

Comment: @MishaFauzel [Что делать когда кто-то ответил на мой вопрос?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: а ещё вы не могли бы посоветовать где почитать именно про то какие методы когда вызываются(кроме документации)

Comment: про какие методы вы говорите ?

Comment: я не знаю как именно это называется, но вот например в том коде что написали вы, я правильно понимаю что в начале вызывается метод newView, там создаётся пустой View, который затем передаётся в bindView, которая заполняет его данными из Cursor-а? то есть именно что за чем идёт и что куда передаётся( да вообщем то про любые методы,чем больше тем лучше) @pavlofff

Comment: Боюсь, что всей этой информации в одном месте ( или даже в каком то вразумительном количестве мест) не существует. В андроид тысячи классов, в каждом до десятков методов. Про что то написано то там, то в другом месте, про что то нет - единственный надежный способ узнать, как все работает - изучать исходники, андроид открытая система.

Comment: В общем то все публичные методы всех классов указаны в почему то нелюбимой вами документации android - все их можно переопределить для своих нужд. Реальное же значение имеет не то, в какой последовательности они вызываются, а то, что они делают (это тоже указано лучше всего в документации, если говорить об одном месте) и что можете сделать вы в этом месте, переопределив данный метод.

Comment: и спасибо большое за совет по поводу ViewHolder, без него это не сделать, потому что при прокрутке данные, введённые  в EditView, остаются на своих местах и создают нехилую такую путаницу, а всё из за того что Android экономит ресурсы и использует одни и те же view по многу раз