# Edittext в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

Я работал с данными только, то есть на Itemы RecyclerView отпрвлял только данные и на RecyclerView выводились эти данные. Но мне сейчас не нужно отправлять данные а вывести на айтемах Edittextы чтобы наоборот оттуда получать данные. Не могу понять, создал Разметку для RecyclerView, сам recyclerView создал, адаптеры тоже создал. Но теперь на MainActivity не могу вывести, потому что нужно ввести на адаптер какие то данные для вывода иначе пустой экран, так вот как это реализовать? или дайте ссылки на туториалы по данной теме... Не смог найти ибо не знаю как правильно сформулировать вопрос...

Правка: Одна разметка с Едитами. и три категории и подкатегой может быть несколько. И в каждой под категории по одной разметке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Вам надо в RecyclerView отобразить Edittextы с заранее введённым текстом?..

Comment: возможно вам поможет [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446178/177345)

Comment: Нет, в том то и дело что нужно отобразить пустой EditText

Comment: А он у вас не пустой получается?.. Всё ещё совершенно не понятно что же вам надо, что вы пытались и что не получилось.

Comment: Пустые Editы нежно вывести...

Comment: 1) Покажите код адаптера, и как вы его устанавливаете в recycleview во фрагменте/активити. 2) Есть ли тут вообще необходимость в использовании этих компонентов? Ведь если список не должен скроллится, то не проще ли его сделать одной разметкой?

Comment: Да , количество молодых пожилых может увеличится, поэтому скролл нужен. Щас я удалил придется заново делать, стараюсь на expandable ListView делать тоже не получается... А то которая с ошибкми, я делал по этой статье не получилоь https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiChb6WupXLAhUDP5oKHSj9C60QjxwIAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bignerdranch.com%2Fblog%2Fexpand-a-recyclerview-in-four-steps%2F&psig=AFQjCNGOjpNVBJrZrVqu-MOPxUJFsrlEJg&ust=1456576947686425

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте вот это: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31860393/5892568 и если объеденить с Expandable RecyclerView получится вот так в их демке:
https://gist.github.com/mserge/5eb5df88f8ea07ee6fba

```
public class IngridientTextChangeListener implements TextWatcher {
    private Ingredient position;

    public void updatePosition(Ingredient position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        // no op
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
       if(null != position) position.setmName(charSequence.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        // no op
    }

}
public class IngredientViewHolder extends ChildViewHolder {

private EditText mIngredientTextView;
private IngridientTextChangeListener mListener;

public IngredientViewHolder(View itemView, IngridientTextChangeListener listener) {
    super(itemView);
    mIngredientTextView = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ingredient_texedit);
    mListener = listener;
    mIngredientTextView.addTextChangedListener(mListener);
}

public void bind(Ingredient ingredient) {
    mListener.updatePosition(ingredient); // set  this first because unless it will be fired
    mIngredientTextView.setText(ingredient.getName());
}
}
```

Неаккуратно со ссылкой на объекты модели - но думаю сильно течь не должно

[image: Вот так на девайсе:]

Comment: Спасибо, попробую, обьязательно отпишусь...

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно создать пустые Items для своего Adapter, а в самом адаптере их не заполнять, а только объявить.

Answer (score 0):

Если предположить, что вы вот так описываете Item:

```
class Item
{
    public enum Type {CATEGORY, SUBCATEGORY}

    public Item(Type type, String title, String value)
    {
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

Вам нужно создать пустой список и добавить в него все необходимые категории и подкатегории:

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

items.add(Item.Type.CATEGORY, "Пожилые", "");
items.add(Item.Type.SUBCATEGORY, "Имя", "");
items.add(Item.Type.SUBCATEGORY, "Фамилия", "");
//...
items.add(Item.Type.CATEGORY, "Молодые", "");
items.add(Item.Type.SUBCATEGORY, "Имя", "");
//...
```

После этого, при инициализации адаптера, передать ему созданный список:

```
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new NewArrayAdapter(context, items);
```

После этого уже внутри адаптера показываем или лейаут с TextView, или с EditText.

Comment: Не совсем понятно((