# ListView повторяет item (при скроллировании)

Tags: android, listview

При скроллировании значения, которые я ввожу в поля AutoCompleteTextView or to EditText повторяется при добавлении items-operations (добавляю item из Activity) и прокручиваю книзу. Т. е. с виду похоже на то, что items повторяются, причем в некотором. Пытался найти ответ, но по форумам решения не помогли, что бы я ни делал с viewHolder, viewInflate, менял бы место инициализации, проблема не уходила. Всем спасибо за внимание!

Внизу мой адаптер OperationAdapter.java---------------------------------

```
class OperationAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public ArrayList<Operation> operations;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> operationns = new ArrayList<>();

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");        

    public OperationAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Operation> operations) {
        this.operations = operations;
        this.context = context;
        operationns.add("Maltcev");
        operationns.add("Loskut");
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return operations.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return operations.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater lInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.operation_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.timeEndOperation = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeEndOperation);
            holder.etc = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etc);
            holder.deleteOperationBut = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteOperation);
            holder.saveOperationBut = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.saveOperation);
            holder.startTimeBut = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.startTimeBut);
            holder.finishTimeBut = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.finishTimeBut);
            holder.timeBeginOperation = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeBeginningOperation);
            holder.operationsAutocomplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.operationAutocomplete);

            convertView.setTag(holder);



        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }



        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterOperations = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, operationns);
        holder.operationsAutocomplete.setAdapter(adapterOperations);


        operations.get(position).timeOfStart = holder.timeBeginOperation.getText().toString();
        operations.get(position).timeOfFinish = holder.timeEndOperation.getText().toString();
        operations.get(position).etc = String.valueOf(position);
        operations.get(position).nameOfOperation = holder.operationsAutocomplete.getText().toString();

        final ViewHolder viewHolderFinal = holder;


        holder.deleteOperationBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                viewHolderFinal.timeBeginOperation.clearComposingText();
                viewHolderFinal.timeEndOperation.clearComposingText();
                viewHolderFinal.etc.clearComposingText();
                viewHolderFinal.operationsAutocomplete.clearComposingText();


                operations.remove(position); 
                notifyDataSetChanged();     
            }
        });

        holder.startTimeBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String currentStartTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                viewHolderFinal.timeBeginOperation.setText(currentStartTime);
            }
        });

        holder.finishTimeBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String currentEndTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                viewHolderFinal.timeEndOperation.setText(currentEndTime);
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    public void addNewOperationCard() {
        Operation operation = new Operation("", "", "", "");
        operations.add(operation);
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public EditText timeBeginOperation;
        public EditText timeEndOperation;
        public EditText etc;
        public AutoCompleteTextView operationsAutocomplete;
        public Button deleteOperationBut;
        public Button saveOperationBut;
        public Button startTimeBut;
        public Button finishTimeBut;
    }
}
```

и блок кода из Activity, где добавляются элементы в ListView:

```
final ListView operationListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.operationListView);

final OperationAdapter operationAdapter = new OperationAdapter(this, operations);
operationListView.setAdapter(operationAdapter);

Button addOperationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addOperationButton);
addOperationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        operationAdapter.addNewOperationCard();
        operationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(OperationAndWorkerActivity.this, operations.size() + " " + operationAdapter.operations.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы биндите данные на айтем только при нажатии на кнопки. При такой логике, кэшированные значения не будут удалятся, если не нажимать на кнопку. Вам нужно в методе `getView()` адаптера **явно** указывать, какие именно данные должны быть отображены в айтеме с текущей позицией (без всяких нажатий и условий). например (я не понял из кода, что в айтеме должно отображаться, если кнопку не нажали, но какое то значение должно быть присвоено):

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ....

    viewHolderFinal.timeBeginOperation.setText("some value");
    viewHolderFinal.timeEndOperation.setText("another some value");

    ...

    return convertView;
}
```

то есть, для каждого виджета в айтеме должно быть однозначно указано, что в нем отображать в текущей позиции (а не только при нажатии на кнопку).Так нужно делать для всех виджетов на айтеме, значения которых меняются.

PS: Так же стоит заметить, что практика получения значений из виджетов ни до чего хорошего вас не доведет (как тут):

```
operations.get(position).timeOfStart = holder.timeBeginOperation.getText().toString()
```

получайте значение из самого источника данных, а не его отображения на экране.

Comment: Спасибо! С логикой прояснилось! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поступить, что сделать при ситуации - пользователь вводит данные но не сохраняет и добавляет массово item. 
Нужно как-то так сохранять значения, которые введены, но никуда не занесены?

Comment: String a = holder.timeBeginOperation.getText().toString();
        String b = holder.timeEndOperation.getText().toString();
        String c = holder.etc.getText().toString();
        String d = holder.operationsAutocomplete.getText().toString();

        final ViewHolder viewHolderFinal = holder;

        viewHolderFinal.timeBeginOperation.setText(a);
        viewHolderFinal.timeEndOperation.setText(b);
        viewHolderFinal.etc.setText(c);
        viewHolderFinal.operationsAutocomplete.setText(d);
По умолчанию, незаполненные поля item пусты - ""

Comment: насчет ввода в EditText - как [то так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446178/177345) это делается

Comment: Ваша последняя ссылка на пост про фокус сильно помогла в контексте использования фокус-Листенера в моем адаптере. Все получилось. Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Ячейки в списке переиспользуются для оптимизации. Т.е. не каждый раз при промотке списка разметка загружается из `xml` файла. Если есть уже загруженная - будет отображена она. Там, естественно, будет информация не нужной ячейки, а закэшированной. Вы же это в коде не учитываете и назначаете текст в ячейку только при загрузке разметки из `xml`. Просто перенесите код назначения текста сразу после получения экземпляра холдера:

```
if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater lInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.operation_item, null);

    holder = new ViewHolder();

    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
}

holder.timeEndOperation = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeEndOperation);
holder.etc = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etc);
holder.deleteOperationBut = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteOperation);
holder.saveOperationBut = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.saveOperation);
holder.startTimeBut = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.startTimeBut);
holder.finishTimeBut = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.finishTimeBut);
holder.timeBeginOperation = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeBeginningOperation);
holder.operationsAutocomplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.operationAutocomplete);

//ТУТ НАДО УСТАНОВИТЬ ТЕКСТ, КАРТИНКИ И ПРОЧЕЕ ДЛЯ ВСЕХ ЭЛеМЕНТОВ РАЗМЕТКИ
```

Comment: Юрий, спасибо за ответ! Сейчас с логикой этого действия прояснилось, но все равно повторяются item при скроллировании... (до этого подобное делал, но не помогло) Возможно, еще нужно как-то сбрасывать вью?

Comment: получить ссылки на виджеты это же не установить в них значение

Comment: @pavlofff, да, действительно) Что-то я поторопился)